# (Re)Define a character within newcommand

Tags: macros, environments

I thought my issue was an easy one, but it doesn't work the way I want it to work. I want a certain (new) command be redefined within another (new) command. The MWE is clear, I think:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newcommand{\transcr}[1]{\textit{#1}
    \renewcommand{\schwa}{\textsuperscript{ə}}}
\newcommand{\schwa}{ə}

\begin{document}
In normal context, \schwa\ appears as it should.\\
In a different place it needs to be \transcr{sup\schwa rscript}, but it isn't\\
And then it doesn't appear as it should in normal context anymore: \schwa.
\end{document}
```

This gives the following result:
[image: Wrong ə's]

I tried to interchange the \newcommand and \renewcommand commands, but without good result. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your example works as expected; `\textit{\renewcommand\schwa{\textsuperscript{ə}}#1}` should be the definition of `\transcr`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd define `\schwa` with a conditional:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newcommand{\transcr}[1]{%
  \textit{\transcrtrue #1}%
}

\newif\iftranscr % starts out false
\DeclareRobustCommand{\schwa}{%
  \iftranscr\textsuperscript{ə}\else ə\fi
}

\begin{document}
In normal context, \schwa\ appears as it should.

In a different place it needs to be \transcr{sup\schwa rscript}, but it isn't

And then it doesn't appear as it should in normal context anymore: \schwa.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Since `\transcrtrue` is issued in the group provided by `\textit`, its effect is confined to it.

A slightly different approach allows for directly using `ə` (but also `\schwa`, if you prefer):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newcommand{\transcr}[1]{%
  \textit{\transcrtrue #1}%
}

\newif\iftranscr % starts out false
\newunicodechar{ə}{%
  \iftranscr\textsuperscript{ə}\else ə\fi
}
\newcommand{\schwa}{ə} % must be done _after_ \newunicodechar{ə}{...}

\begin{document}
In normal context, ə appears as it should.

In a different place it needs to be \transcr{supərscript}, but it isn't

And then it doesn't appear as it should in normal context anymore: ə.

\bigskip

In normal context, \schwa\ appears as it should.

In a different place it needs to be \transcr{sup\schwa rscript}, but it isn't

And then it doesn't appear as it should in normal context anymore: \schwa.

\end{document}
```

You can also nest conditionals:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newcommand{\transcr}[1]{%
  \textit{\transcrtrue #1}%
}
\newcommand{\phon}[1]{%
  \textbf{\phontrue #1}%
}

\newif\iftranscr % starts out false
\newif\ifphon % starts out false
\newunicodechar{ə}{%
  \iftranscr
    \textsuperscript{ə}%
  \else     
    \ifphon
      \textsubscript{/ə/}%
    \else
      ə%   
    \fi
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\schwa}{ə} % must be done _after_ \newunicodechar{ə}{...}

\begin{document}
In normal context, ə appears as it should.

In a different place it needs to be \transcr{supərscript}, and it is;        
likewise it could be \phon{supərscript}.

And then it doesn't appear as it should in normal context anymore: ə.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, that works! A step further: what if I want a character in two different groups? E.g., let's say that ə in \transcr should be superscript, but in \phon it should be subscript (not so realistic, but it works as an example, I think). Simply copying the code and replacing \transcr and \iftranscr with \phon and \ifphon gives an error.

Comment: @Jopie I added a possible way, there are others.

Answer (score 5):

You need to exchange the order of the instructions `\textit{#1}` and `\renewcommand{\schwa}{\textsuperscript{ə}}`. In addition, both instructions need to be enclosed in a TeX group to limit the scope of the redefinition of `\schwa`.

```
\newcommand{\transcr}[1]{%
    {\renewcommand{\schwa}{\textsuperscript{ə}}%
    \textit{#1}}}
```

---

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newcommand{\transcr}[1]{%
    {\renewcommand{\schwa}{\textsuperscript{ə}}%
    \textit{#1}}}
\newcommand{\schwa}{ə}

\begin{document}
In normal context, \schwa\ appears as it should.

In a different place it needs to be \transcr{sup\schwa rscript}, and now it does.

And when it reappears in normal context --- \schwa\ --- things are still OK.
\end{document}
```