# Command Defining Nested Command

Tags: macros, nesting

I'm trying to define a command which, upon being called with a certain parameter, 'renews' a different command. In particular, I tried the following (it doesn't work!).

```
\newcommand{\gap} %initialise \gap to exist
\newcommand{\GAP}{1}{
    \renewcommand{\gap}{\hspace{#1 em}} }
```

My idea was that `\GAP{3}` redefines `\gap` to `\hspace{3em}`, for example.

I've looked at a few TeX.SE questions, in particular [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/396293/redefine-a-character-within-newcommand), but I can't see how to correct this...

Incidentally, removing the space between `#1` and `em` doesn't work, and putting two `#`-s outputs 13 (for `\GAP{3}`).

---

Here's a full MWE.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\newcommand{\gap}{} %initialise \gap to exist
\newcommand{\GAP}{1}{
    \renewcommand{\gap}{\hspace{##1em}} }
\begin{document}
\GAP{3}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I feel it did the opposite (hence putting it in), but I've removed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were three things wrong

1. The syntax for `\newcommand` requires the number of arguments in square brackets: `\newcommand{\GAP}[1]{...}`, not curly brackets `\newcommand{\GAP}{1}{...}`
2. The definition of `\gap`, since it does not take its own argument, must be specified as `#1` (i.e., evaluated within the execution of `\GAP`), rather than as `##1` (which would imply that it is an argument to `\gap`)
3. Some stray spaces were in the definition of `\GAP`.

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\newcommand{\gap}{} %initialise \gap to exist
\newcommand{\GAP}[1]{\renewcommand{\gap}{\hspace{#1em}}}
\begin{document}
a\gap b

\GAP{3}
a\gap b
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To 1., well obviously, what on earth was I thinking! =P -- as for 2., that makes sense (I was only trying `##` as I saw it on a different question)

Comment: Plus two unwanted spaces. @SamT You should not have those two spaces around `\renewcommand`. May be a `%` before, but also remove the space *after*.

Comment: Ok, but may I ask why?

Comment: @SamT Why what?

Comment: Sorry, should've tagged @Manuel! Why not the spaces in this case?

Comment: @SamT The stray spaces in the definition will cause spaces to be output whenever `\GAP{}` and `\gap` are invoked, which is probably not what you wanted.

Comment: Fair. what I'm using, it doesn't actually matter, but I see that it's good practice in general. The reason I would tend to put the space after is because if I have a few similar commands, I'd line up all the final `}`-s, just for ease of reading. Probably best not to though, as you've pointed out...

Answer (score 1):

The number of arguments is an optional argument (in brackets) to `\newcommand`. Here is the corrected example:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\newcommand{\gap}{} %initialise \gap to exist
\newcommand{\GAP}[1]{%
    \renewcommand{\gap}{\hspace{#1em}} }
\begin{document}
Text\gap Text\GAP{3}
Text\gap Text
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is not `\GAP` that has an optional argument. `\newcommand` does.

Comment: Yeah, I've realised my silly mistake! Thank you